# tagsinput gem in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, activeadmin

I'm creating a web application where I've used the [active admin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin) gem. Suppose, i've a model named `Category` with fields `names`. Now, in my **names** field i want to insert multiple values by comma separated. And it will look like [this](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/). That's why i've used the [tagsinput](https://github.com/greshny/tagsinput-rails) gem. But its not working.

Anyone have any idea how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would do next.

Add to active_admin.js

```
 //= require jquery.tagsinput


 $(selector).tagsInput({
 'autocomplete_url': url_to_autocomplete_api,
 'autocomplete': { option: value, option: value},
 'height':'100px',
 'width':'300px',
 'interactive':true,
 'defaultText':'add a tag',
 'onAddTag':callback_function,
 'onRemoveTag':callback_function,
 'onChange' : callback_function,
 'removeWithBackspace' : true,
 'minChars' : 0,
 'maxChars' : 0 //if not provided there is no limit,
 'placeholderColor' : '#666666'
});
```

Add to  active_admin.css.scss

```
*= require jquery.tagsinput
```

Make sure that you have an action in controller that would create new category. Check if you have it in your routes.rb and that will be your

```
'autocomplete_url': url_to_autocomplete_api
```

I didn't try to do all these step. But I think I should give you some ideas.

If that wouldn't work I would add js and css files to my assets directly from [tagsinput](https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input)

If you choose go this way you may need add your js and css to initializer/assets.rb

```
 Rails.application.config.assets.precompile +=  %w()
```

I hope it helps.